# getting the value of font and putting storing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$('select[name="content_fonts"]').change(function(){
    $('.leftpanel').css('font-family', $(this).find(":selected").text());
    $('#panelfont').val($(this));
```

im trying to get the value of the font being inserted into .leftpnael class
and putting in the #panelfont value!! but its giving `[object object]`!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` will not return the font, as it refers to the `#panelfont` element. You need `$('.leftpanel').css('font-family')` instead:

```
$('#panelfont').val($('leftpanel').css('font-family'));
```